# delete comment using fadeOut command (Ajax)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I just watch a vid from http://railsforzombiestwo.codeschool.com/levels/5 which the vid show a tutorial on how to make a delete link fade out with Ajax (from 8:40 - 11:00). i try to do it but its failed.. no fade out and disappear / page not refreshed. after i click the delete button, i've to refresh the page manually to make it disappear. here is my code :

controller:

```
def destroy
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to post_path}
        format.js 
    end

end
```

views : views/_comment.html.erb

```
<% if current_user && current_user.id == @post.user_id %>
<p>
<%= link_to 'Delete', [comment.post, comment],
           method: :delete,
           remote: true,
           class: "button" %>
</p>
<% end %>
</div>
```

destroy.js.erb

```
$('#<%= dom_id(@comment) %>').fadeOut();
```

from the codeschool(railsforzombiestwo), it shows that only 3 step needed. I try and its not working for me. Almost 2 month of learning rails with no basic programming ^^'. Help me??

Comment: Where is `dom_id` method?

Comment: you mean the def method? i dont see dom_id method in the tutorial though

Comment: What is the html `id ` of the element you are deleting? Somewhere there must be a method called `dom_id` that you have used here `$('#<%= dom_id(@comment) %>')`

Comment: Can you paste the html of comment which you are showing in your view?

Comment: @Nami please check my answer

Comment: @Nami Edited the answer, you can try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `id` to this div element `<div class="comment clearfix">`

```
<div class="comment clearfix" id="comment_<%= comment.id %>">
```

Then in destroy.js.erb do this

```
$("#comment_<%= @comment.id %>").fadeOut();
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: not working :( can u show the example of dom_id() method? cuz i just copy the code from the tutorial.. there is no method for dom_id showed

Comment: Thanks it work! wow i love this forum !! full of expert helping a beginner like me... thanks a lot Mr!

Comment: Glad it helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="comment clearfix" id="comment-<%= comment.id %>">
  <div class="comment_content">
    <p class="comment_name">
      <strong><%= comment.name %></strong>
    </p>
    <p class="comment_body"><%= comment.body %></p>
    <p class="comment_time"><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago</p>
    </div>
      <% if current_user && current_user.id == @post.user_id %>
        <p> <%= link_to 'Delete', [comment.post, comment], method: :delete, remote: true, class: "button" %> </p>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

$("#comment-<%= @comment.id %>").fadeOut();
```

Comment: i change the minus symbol `$("#comment-<%= @comment.id %>").fadeOut();` to underscore `$("#comment_<%= @comment.id %>").fadeOut();` and it works! thx a lot!

Comment: If possible always use class name with `-` instead of `_`, mostly `_` are using for variable.

Comment: i tried and it works! basically your code is the right answer from start.. lol i just copy the destroy.js.erb code only.. thats why i have to change the `-` to `_` ^^'